# Difference of two query results in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say we've indexes of e-commerce store data, and we want to get the difference of list of products which are present in 2 stores.

Information on the index content: A sample data stored in each document looks like below:

```
{
   "product_name": "sample 1",
   "store_slug": "store 1",
   "sales_count": 42,
   "date": "2018-04-04"
}
```

Below are queries which gets me all products present in 2 stores individually,

```
Data for store 1

curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/store/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
   {
       "_source": ["product_name"],
       "query": {
           "constant_score" : {
               "filter" : {
                    "bool" : {
                       "must" : [
                           { "term" : { "store_slug" : "store_1"}}]}}}}}'

Data for store 2

curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/store/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
   {
       "_source": ["product_name"],
       "query": {
           "constant_score" : {
               "filter" : {
                    "bool" : {
                       "must" : [
                           { "term" : { "store_slug" : "store_2"}}]}}}}}'
```

Is it possible with elasticsearch query to get the difference of both result(without doing using some script/ other languages)?

E.g. of above operation: Let's say "store 1" is selling products ["product 1", "product 2"] and "store 2" is selling products ["product 1", "product 3"], So expected output of difference of products of "store 1" and "store 2" is "product 2".

Answer (score 1):

Why not doing it in a single query?

Products that are in store 1 but not in store 2:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/store/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
  "_source": [
    "product_name"
  ],
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "term": {
                "store_slug": "store_1"
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "store_slug": "store_2"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

You can easily do the opposite, too.

**UPDATE**

After reading your updates, I think the best way to solve this is using `terms` aggregations, first by product and then by store and only select the products for which there is only a single store bucket (using a pipeline aggregation)

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/store/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "products": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "product_name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "stores": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "store_slug"
          }
        },
        "min_bucket_selector": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "count": "stores._bucket_count"
            },
            "script": {
              "source": "params.count == 1"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Val, Above will not get the difference, for e.g. lets say store 1 has products "a,b,c" and store 2 has products "a,b,d". Expected output of "store1 - store 2" should be "c" and "store 2 - store 1" will be "d"

Comment: `store_slug` is an array of store slugs ? i.e. you only have a single product document and it can be available in several stores (via the slugs), or you have a product document per store ?

Comment: store_slug is a single value field, So each document in the index is sales information of a product of given store. So whole data structure(of a single document) looks like: "{'store_slug': 'abc', 'product_name': 'sample1', 'sales_count': 12}"

Comment: I suggest you update your question with the mapping and one or two sample documents

Comment: So that means that if you've sold the product "sample 1" in "store 2" 36 times, you'd have another document for the same product, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168819/discussion-between-neo-and-val).

Comment: Hey Val, Can you check once the change, looks same to me. Can you point me to change, If i'm missing anything

Comment: Use the second query in my answer, which is totally different form the first one.

Comment: Val, Till now I've not used pipeline aggregation, checking on that. In your answer code i'm not able to see where the value for store(store1) or product(sample1) is given

Comment: That one should do exactly what you expect, i.e. show you only products that have been sold in a single shop and not two, so it does the two diffs (store1-store2 and store2-store1) in one shot

Comment: Val: Extremely sorry for late reply, above wasn't working for me. I did 2 separate queries to get the product which are present in given store and which are present on others and then took diff at the application layer.

Comment: Weird, pretty sure it would have worked. What wasn't working exactly? What results differed from what you expected?

Comment: Result returned from that was : ""aggregations" : {
    "products" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 23878,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 14130146,
      "buckets" : [ ]
    }", 2 points here: 1st result which I was expecting is exact list of products, 2nd lets say if we have more that 2 stores present in documents, will this produce correct result, so basically can above query be parametrized for store_slug as key value

Comment: There must be a reason why you get an empty list of buckets

Comment: Not getting reason for that.

Comment: I was able to get results based on the same data you provided above... Feel free to create a gist with a full recreation of the commands that would allow me to reproduce what you're seeing.